# CSS nth-child of alternative

Tags: javascript, css

I have the following application using [html5sortable](https://github.com/lukasoppermann/html5sortable/tree/master#docs)

```js
const sorter = sortable("#sortable", {
  placeholderClass: "placeholder"
})[0];
sorter.addEventListener("sortstart", function(e) {
  // hide list counter when dragging
  e.detail.item.classList.add("list-drag");
});

sorter.addEventListener("sortstop", function(e) {
  // show list counter when finished dragging
  e.detail.item.classList.remove("list-drag");
});
```

```css
ol {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  counter-reset: item;
  padding-left: 40px;
}

ol>li {
  margin: 0.5rem;
  counter-increment: item;
  position: relative;
}

ol>li::before {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  content: counter(item);
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  left: -49px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

li {
  height: 64px;
  width: 256px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 2px;
}

li:nth-child(1)::before {
  background-color: gold;
}

li:nth-child(2)::before {
  background-color: silver;
}

li:nth-child(3)::before {
  background-color: #C5832B;
}

.placeholder {
  border-style: dashed;
}

.list-drag::before {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5sortable/0.13.3/html5sortable.min.js" integrity="sha512-3btxfhQfasdVcv1dKYZph5P7jFeeLRcF1gDVzFA+k9AiwwhB1MNI7O58zCK0uVItuMHNDR5pMoF2nqlCGzUwZQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<ol id="sortable">
  <li>alpha</li>
  <li>beta</li>
  <li>gamma</li>
  <li>delta</li>
</ol>
```

When an item is dragged, html5sortable applies `display: none` to it until it is dropped but `nth-child` still counts it as a child so the counter colours aren't right while dragging. I can get it to work with the following

```
li:nth-child(1 of :not(.list-drag))::before{
    background-color: gold;
}
li:nth-child(2 of :not(.list-drag))::before{
    background-color: silver;
}
li:nth-child(3 of :not(.list-drag))::before{
    background-color: #C5832B;
}
```

but this is a relatively new CSS feature which isn't fully supported. Is there any way to achieve this with better supported CSS or Javascript/jQuery?

Comment: on which browser this isn't yet supported? the support cover all the modern browsers: https://caniuse.com/css-nth-child-of